# Queries in controller only if .js format (not if .html)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, controller

Take the standard controller action redirect code:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to companies_url }
  format.js
end
```

Is there a way to only perform a couple of additional queries if the format is .js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, just add them in the `format.js` responder block

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to companies_url }
  format.js {
    couple(:of)
    additional_queries
  }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to handle only .js format from action you can specify `respond_to :js` like this:

```
class SomeController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :js
  def some_action
  ...
  end
end
```

..and this action will respond only to .js format. Or you can use `request.xhr?` in your action to verify incoming format.